# Sequence in the unit circle

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, limits, analysis

I am trying to prove the following:

Lemma: Let $ (\lambda_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset \{\lambda\in\mathbb{C} : |\lambda| = 1\} $ be a sequence. Then there is a sequence  $ (m(k))_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ of positive intergers such that: $$\lim_{k\to\infty} \lambda_{n}^{m(k)} = 1 \ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$$

The hint is to use Cantor's diagonalization process, but I don't see where I'd get from it.

$$\lambda_{1} \lambda_{2} \lambda_{3} \lambda_{4} \lambda_{5} \lambda_{6} \lambda_{7} \ldots \lambda_{n} \ldots\\\lambda_{1}^{2} \lambda_{2}^{2} \lambda_{3}^{2} \lambda_{4}^{2} \lambda_{5}^{2} \lambda_{6}^{2} \lambda_{7}^{2} \ldots \lambda_{n}^{2} \ldots \\ \vdots$$

Comment: When you say unit sphere, do you mean unit disc in the complex plane?  I'm having trouble parsing this...

Comment: Yes. Let me edit that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $k\in\mathbb N$. Then $\lambda_k$ either is or is not a root of unity. If it is, take $m_k\in\mathbb N$ such that ${\lambda_k}^{m_k}=1$. Otherwise, the set $\{{\lambda_k}^n\mid k\in\mathbb N\}$ is dense in the unit circle. So, take $m_k\in\mathbb N$ such that $\lvert{\lambda_k}^{m_k}-1\rvert<\frac1k$. Then$$\lim_{k\to\infty}{\lambda_k}^{m_k}=1.$$

Comment: This does not imply $\forall n\colon\lim_{k\to \infty}\lambda_n^{m_k}=1$